# ASP.NET MVC controller - where to register?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I inherited this project and I need to expand this API controller.  I need to add the commented out lines, when I add them, it crashes with a default error. I think the controller isn't being registered / initialized properly. I have search the project to see if I can find where the controller is being initialized but I can not find it.

The underlying error is this:

> Exception = {"An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'EstimatorController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor."}

```
    [RoutePrefix("API")]
    public class EstimatorController : BaseController
    {
        private IAppointmentTypeService appointmentTypeService = null;
        private IClientCptCodeService cptCodeService = null;
        private IStandAloneEstimatorService standAloneEstimator = null;
        private IMedicareFeeImport medicareFeeService = null;
        private IAPIRequestLogService requestLogService = null;
        private ICGXTemplate cgxTemplateService = null;
        private IAppointmentTypeService apptTypeService = null;
        private IClientLocationService locationService = null;

        public EstimatorController(IAppointmentTypeService appointmentTypeService, IClientCptCodeService cptCodeService, 
                                 IStandAloneEstimatorService standAloneEstimator, IMedicareFeeImport medicareFeeService
                               , IAPIRequestLogService requestLogService )
            //, ICGXTemplate cgxTemplateService,
            // IClientLocationService locationService
        {
            this.appointmentTypeService = appointmentTypeService;
            this.standAloneEstimator = standAloneEstimator;
            this.cptCodeService = cptCodeService;
            this.medicareFeeService = medicareFeeService;
            this.requestLogService = requestLogService;
            //this.cgxTemplateService = cgxTemplateService;
            //this.locationService = locationService;
        }
    }
```

Comment: *"An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'EstimatorController'."* - Is there any additional information in the exception, such as an inner exception or other properties with more info?  Presumably you wouldn't need a parameterless constructor because the existing code already works, so it sounds more likely that the dependency injection isn't able to create instances of the new services.  **Those** probably need to be registered (in whatever way the existing ones are already registered), not the controller itself.

Comment: You need to register the `ICGXTemplate` and `IClientLocationService`. Fast way to do that. search for `IClientLocationService` and check where it is registered.

Comment: @David   Yes this is the inner exception 

InnerException = {"None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'xxx.APIServices.Controllers.EstimatorController' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:\r\nCannot resolve parameter

Comment: @Rob: It sounds more and more like the dependency injector needs these new services configured.  You'd need to find where that happens for the current services.  In simple applications it likely uses the built-in dependency injection framework and is performed in (or invoked by) the startup code.  But there's no guarantee of that.  Doing a global search in the project(s) for the other service interfaces used here should be able to find it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks David!  Root cause is DependencyRegister.cs - the new items need to be configured there like this.

```
builder.Register(s => new CGXService()).As<ICGXService>().InstancePerRequest();
```